# Error message excel no macro if possible?

Tags: vba, excel, popup

I have an excel with a column called `Types` that contains a list of activities, and another one called `Ball name`. What i have to do is;
if i selected `football` activity the `Ball name` column becomes required. So if the user not compile the `Ball name` column i want that a error message comes out.
I tried to go in `Data Validation` and i found the possibility to create a popup error. In the first tab "Settings" i can create an if statement that i need but i don't know what i have to write. It's the first time i use excel. I need something like

```
=IF(C1242="football";"true_condition";"False_condition")
```

where the true condition is that i need to insert the value in the `Ball name` column and if i  don't remember to insert it the error message comes out.
How can i do? I prefer don't use macro if possible.

Comment: You must specify better what you want: Excel doesn't `compile` as referred. Data validation occur when a cell is changed. If you put a validation on `Types`, pop up will appear before user can enter data in `Ball name`. Specify better what behavior do you pretend?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need a pop up error, you can just use conditional formatting, something like:

```
    A           B
1 Types      Ball Name
2 Football
```

So, in cell B2, write

```
=IF(A2 = "Football",0)
```

Then go to format cells for that cell > Custom

Type in

```
0;0;[Red]"BALL REQUIRED"
```

And that will throw a big red message in the cell, and drag down as needed.

Comment: This could be a solution...but I don't know if it will accepted..is there a way to show the pop-up? Using the same concept.

Comment: You could also simply put data validation on the type column, say...Custom > Not equal to > "Football" > and change the error alert, which will bring a popup.

Comment: something like `=IF(A2<>"Football",0)`? But it gets me error... i think beacuse i need to write the `;` instead `,` before the 0 but i'm not sure.

Comment: @David_D I believe that error is because you don't have a false condition, so when A2 IS football, excel doesn't know what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Cells are as follows:

```
    A           B          C
1 Types      Ball Name
2 Football
```

In cell C3, input the following formula:

```
=OR(AND(ISBLANK(A2),ISBLANK(B2)),AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A2)),NOT(ISBLANK(B2))))
```

Then do the following:

- Select cell B2
- Click Data>Data Validation
- Select the Settings tab
- Allow: Custom
- Ignore blank: Uncheck
- Formula: =C2
- Select Error Alert Tab
- Show error... : Check
- Chose Style, Title and Error Message as per your liking
- Click OK

Note: The user can still get away from the validation.